# Copy value from jsonb column to another nested jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration

I have an entity that has, among other things, two jsonb columns : "options" and "features". I want to copy data from a field inside the options column to a two levels deep field inside features.
What I've tried :

```sql
UPDATE entity 
SET features = jsonb_set(  features
                         , '{informations}'
                         , "features"->'informations' 
                         ||'{"test": "options"->'test'}'
                         , true);
```

But I get this error when trying to run my migration :

```
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "test"
```

I think that the simple quotes around the {} and test create the error.

How can I do this ?

FYI : the reverse migration is working perfectly with :

```
UPDATE entity 
SET options = jsonb_set(  options
                        , '{test}'
                        , features->'informations'->'test'
                        , true);
```

Because there is no nested simple quotes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only a few of those quotes. You also need to wrap the extractions in parentheses, otherwise they will be evaluated left-to-right, in an unintuitive order: [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XBcVSvJ1)

| features | options |
| --- | --- |
| { "informations": { "features_k121": 121, "features_k122": { "features_k131": 131 } }, "features_k111": 11 } | { "test": { "options_key221": 221 }, "options_key211": 211 } |

```
UPDATE entity 
SET features = jsonb_set(  features
                         , '{informations}'
                         , (features->'informations')
                         ||(options ->'test')
                         , true)
returning jsonb_pretty(features) as features
         ,jsonb_pretty(options) as options;
```

| features | options |
| --- | --- |
| { "informations": { "features_k121": 121, "features_k122": { "features_k131": 131 }, "options_key221": 221 }, "features_k111": 11 } | { "test": { "options_key221": 221 }, "options_key211": 211 } |

That's assuming you want to *copy data* ***from*** *a field inside the `options`*. If you instead want to copy *the entire field*, you can instead use the query below, but note that is not the same thing:

```sql
UPDATE entity 
SET features = jsonb_set(  features
                         , '{informations,test}'
                         , options->'test'
                         , true);
```

| features | options |
| --- | --- |
| { "informations": { "test": { "options_key221": 221 }, "features_k121": 121, "features_k122": { "features_k131": 131 }, "options_key221": 221 }, "features_k111": 11 } | { "test": { "options_key221": 221 }, "options_key211": 211 } |

---

The unintuitive behaviour I'm referring to is this (shown in [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XBcVSvJ1)):

```sql
features -> 'informations' || options -> 'test'
```

Being evaluated like this:

```sql
((features -> 'informations') || options) -> 'test'
```

And not like this

```sql
(features -> 'informations') || (options -> 'test')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
But would this add a "test" field inside "informations" ?

Comment: No, it would merge whatever object is under `options.test` key, into the structure of `features.informations`. If you add some sample/mock records and example result you want to get, it would be easier to devise a query.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was :

```
UPDATE domain
SET features = jsonb_set(features, '{informations,test}', "options"->'test', true)
```

Comment: That's not what you specified, so make sure that's really what's required. This doesn't copy data *from* the `test` field, it copies *the entire field* and everything in it. See the updates in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77627270/5298879) and [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XBcVSvJ1).

Comment: This is what I meant, sorry if my question was misleading. I've accepted your detailed answer though. Thank you again.